# logstash limit the size of output file

Tags: output, logstash, filesize

I am running logstash 6.8.11, using logstash to retrieve logs from a filebeat.

The configuration is quite simple:

```
input {
beats {
    port => hidden
}
}
output {
if [beat][name] =~ "anonymous*" {
    file {
    path => "/tmp/test-%{+YYYY-MM-DD-HH}"
    codec => json_lines
}
}}
```

Is there any way I can limit the size of the output file to a specific size (let's say 10MB, or 50MB)

Answer (score 2):

The file output does not support log rotation based on size itself. There is a long standing open issue that directly speaks to that [here](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-file/issues/57) (and related issues [here](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-file/issues/34) and [here](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-file/issues/10)). The response from the elastic developers was that you can use existing tools like logrotate to do rotation.

Comment: thank you for tou response. At the moment logs are written every hour. Maybe I can force them to be writen at a different interval? Let's say 30 minutes? How would I need to modifiy the path format in order to achieve this?

Comment: I do not think the file output can change the file every 30 minutes. Every hour, or even every minute, but not multiples of that. The file output is calling [StringInterpolation.evaluate](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/blob/2f890abab19444bd9902639cb66835fd80785c06/logstash-core/src/main/java/org/logstash/StringInterpolation.java#L61), which calls a [joda](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/blob/master/src/main/java/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.java) function. And I do not think that joda supports it.